# flow error: property is missing in ... but exists in

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have this code:

```
type Data = Num | Str;
type Num = {n: number};
type Str = {s: string};

function printNum({n}: Num) {
  console.log(n);
}

function printStr({s}: Str) {
  console.log(s);
}

function loadData(t: 'Num' | 'Str'): Data {
  if (t === 'Num') {
      return {n: 123};
  } else {
      return {s: 'abc'};
  }
}

const data = loadData('Num');

printNum(data);
```

This does not type-check: `Cannot call 'printNum' with 'data' bound to the first parameter because property 'n' is missing in 'Str' [1] but exists in 'Num' [2]`.

How can I use a variable that can contain either of several (different, non-unifiable) types? Do I have to use two separate variables, one for each type?

https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UByBXAtlAPlAZWACcBuAKFEnWxSgG8A7ALikewCMJiBfCq6EWJ16AZ1aiSAS0YBzPuXIAzDIwDGwKQHtGUMMRnBMWABRMerYwEoG5KFDU7RWgDYQAdC62yTjKxR5FFXVNHT0DRmAhM1ELQhIbejsHJ1cPLx9Rf3JA5VUNbV0vOAATeEQTYFYAcmNqvChqoWqrVnKkJPspJShKlGRUWuwW23sxqGIIYAxiXSZWAEYAJgBmBXseKAgXUWhO8YmpmbnxRrgONWr1qEDcx0ZJKBKEJFRispeTIawWinJ9QzGEzPRDZIA

Comment: If you can write an example that reproduces the error on http://fow.org/try it would be easier to take a crack that this. FWIW, this looks like it's probably tackle-able.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question, added a link to flow.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of thing is hard to typecheck with Flow. You can typecheck the code that *uses* this function, but typechecking inside the function will be hard/incomplete (from what I know). One way to typecheck code that *uses* this function is to declare a hypothetical function that does what you want and then use the typeof that function:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UByBXAtlAPlAZWACcBuAKFEnWxSgG8A7ALikewCMJiBfCq6EWJ16AZ1aiSAS0YBzPuXIAzDIwDGwKQHtGUMMRnBMWABRMerACQAlCHAAmAeUYAbEAB5jAPgCUDclBQajqiWi4QAHQuWrImjD4UPIoq6po6egaMwEJmohZQNnZOrh5Cvv6BwYyh4VExJqIJ5Enk9hBqLnDE0Cka2rpSbXAuAGKqaibArADkQtM+rEKt7Z3dUL1pA0Oj45MzxvOsxopVklDRDvCIrAJaSlCDdjvqdJN+yF4VD-eTKMio0wOfnoAUCYO6wAwxF0JjMLCgAEYAEwAZnyxgWUDgjBACSgAHp8YQMGB9BBRKIoAB3LqMGSySlUgAWUnCUEkrJcUAg1Sh9Op0AhUN0SGOgR43JcomgUh+wD+ALmwNBYKgQuhUFhYhmcA4amm+SEmOxuNIBKJBBJZIp1Np9MZLLZHJcXJ5oj5cgFaogkI1SCW4tBwCZxC0VLYEHDAFFiKHiCYAEQASUYADdhoMoAIEz5micQvL7AgkKgLvYrnATIDsPMKOR9IZjCYi4gmkA))

```
type Data = Num | Str;
type Num = {n: number};
type Str = {s: string};

function printNum({n}: $ReadOnly<Num>) {
  console.log(n);
}

function printStr({s}: $ReadOnly<Str>) {
  console.log(s);
}

declare function idealFunc(t: 'Str'): Str
declare function idealFunc(t: 'Num'): Num

const loadData: typeof idealFunc = (t) => {
  if (t === 'Num') {
      return (({n: 123}: Num): any); // Suppress warnings while still ensuring we return a Num
  } else if (t === 'Str') {
      return (({s: 'abc'}: Str): any); // Suppress warnings while still ensuring we return a Str
  }
  throw new Error("Invalid type")
}

const data = loadData('Num');

printNum(data); // look ma, no error
```

You can see this multiple-function-declaration pattern used a lot in the [libdefs for dom elements](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/e4d5845af347bfae7e7aa68fee25801fd09c59fe/lib/dom.js#L591).

In the above examples, I chose to assert the type of the object to either `Str` or `Num`. I'm doing this so we can preserve some level of type safety (e.g. if the type of `Str` or `Num` changes in the future), since `any` suppresses possible problems where we no longer return one of those things. If you don't care about that, you can simplify the typecast to `({...contents...}: any)`